# Simulation of a shopping line using a LinkedQueue

Tags: java, queue

I am just looking for a tip to help me start off this program so I can have multiple "lines". I currently have 1 line and am trying to add two more lines (LinkedQueues). I am required to make a program to have 3 lines. instead of just one line. Im just looking for some possible help on trying to start this program off

```
public class WaitLine
{
  private QueueInterface<Customer> line, line2, line3;
  private int numberOfArrivals;
 // private int numberOfArrivals1;
  //private int numberOfArrivals2;
  //private int numberOfArrivals3;
  private int numberServed;
  private int totalTimeWaited;

  public WaitLine()
  {
    line = new LinkedQueue<>();
    line2 = new LinkedQueue<>();
    line3 = new LinkedQueue<>();

    reset();
  } // end default constructor

  /** Task: Simulates a waiting line with one serving agent.
   *  @param duration  the number of simulated minutes 
   *  @param arrivalProbability  a real number between 0 and 1, and the
   *                             probability that a customer arrives at
   *                             a given time
   *  @param maxTransactionTime  the longest transaction time for a
   *                             customer */ 
  public void simulate(int duration, double arrivalProbability, 
                       int maxTransactionTime)
  {
    int transactionTimeLeft = 0;

    for (int clock = 0; clock < duration; clock++) {
      if (Math.random() < arrivalProbability) {
        numberOfArrivals++;
        int transactionTime = (int)(Math.random() * maxTransactionTime + 1);
        Customer nextArrival = new Customer(clock, transactionTime, numberOfArrivals);
        line.enqueue(nextArrival);

        System.out.println("Customer " + numberOfArrivals 
                         + " enters line at time " + clock 
                         + ". Transaction time is " + transactionTime);

      } // end if

      if (transactionTimeLeft > 0)
        transactionTimeLeft--;

      else if (!line.isEmpty())
      {
        Customer nextCustomer = line.dequeue();
        transactionTimeLeft = nextCustomer.getTransactionTime() - 1;
        int timeWaited = clock - nextCustomer.getArrivalTime();
        totalTimeWaited = totalTimeWaited + timeWaited;
        numberServed++;
        System.out.println("Customer " + nextCustomer.getCustomerNumber()
                         + " begins service at time " + clock 
                        + ". Time waited is " + timeWaited);


      } // end if
    } // end for
  } // end simulate

  /** Task: Displays summary results of the simulation. */ 
  public void displayResults()
  {
      //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("LINE 1:");
    System.out.println("Number served = " + numberServed);
    System.out.println("Total time waited = " + totalTimeWaited);
    double averageTimeWaited = ((double)totalTimeWaited) / numberServed;
    System.out.println("Average time waited = " + averageTimeWaited);
    int leftInLine = numberOfArrivals - numberServed;
    System.out.println("Number left in line = " + leftInLine);
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("LINE 2:");
    System.out.println("Number served = " + numberServed);
    System.out.println("Total time waited = " + totalTimeWaited);
    System.out.println("Average time waited = " + averageTimeWaited);
    System.out.println("Number left in line = " + leftInLine);
  //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("LINE 3:");
    System.out.println("Number served = " + numberServed);
    System.out.println("Total time waited = " + totalTimeWaited);
    System.out.println("Average time waited = " + averageTimeWaited);
    System.out.println("Number left in line = " + leftInLine);
  } // end displayResults

  /** Task: Initializes the simulation. */ 
  public final void reset()
  {
    line.clear();

    numberOfArrivals = 0;
    numberServed = 0;
    totalTimeWaited = 0;
  } // end reset
} // end WaitLine
```

Comment: You understand your problem, but we don't. Please, add some details for your post.

Comment: You could implement round-robin. so 1st customer 1st line, 2nd customer 2nd line, 3rd customer 3rd line, 4th customer 1st line and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `WaitLine` class must represent only one line. Remove `line2, line3` from class members. Then add another client class that will create as many instances of `WaitLine` as needed and call their methods either in a loop or concurrently.